# issue with imagemagic nodejs

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, node-modules

I am leaning nodejs by browsing through the examples in the internet.
I came across a code ,in which I am not getting any output.

```
var file=' H:/node/t/5848069af6b4292040b6e737 ';
const execFile = require('child_process').execFile;
var args = ['-format']
args.push('"%m %z %w %h %b %x %y %f"')
args.push(file)

child = execFile('identify', args, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    var info = {};
    console.log(err);
    console.log(stderr);
    if (stdout) {
         console.log('hurrrrayyyyyyyy  stdout'+stdout);
    } else {
         console.log('no stdout');
    }
});
```

I am getting the error

```
     { Error: spawn identify ENOENT
at exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:359:16)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
at Module.runMain (module.js:606:11)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
code: 'ENOENT',
errno: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'spawn identify',
path: 'identify',
spawnargs:
[ '-format',
 '"%m %z %w %h %b %x %y %f"',
 ' H:/node/t/5848069af6b4292040b6e737 ' ],
cmd: 'identify -format "%m %z %w %h %b %x %y %f"        H:/node/t/5848069af6b4292040b6e737 ' }
```

But when I run the cmd :-identify -format "%m %z %w %h %b %x %y %f"        H:/node/t/5848069af6b4292040b6e737   its working perfectly.  Kindly help me

Comment: Try copying the file to the local directory so that you do not have `H:` in the name - maybe that is upsetting something.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, tried it, still the same error,   I tried to get the output with require('child_process').exec , and the script is working.

Comment: Might just need to have a full path to the `identify` binary, or ensure that the process running node has the correct `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: @emcconville  , but if I try with const execFile = require('child_process').exec and remove the arg for making exec child process to work,its working perfectly

Comment: Might be worth [rereading the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_spawning_bat_and_cmd_files_on_windows). It's ideal for the `shell` environment to spawn; such that, all the delegates and libraries can be found by the child process.